# kustomize: how to pass `newTag` from command line

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I am using https://kustomize.io/ have below is my `kustomization.yaml` file,

I have multiple docker images and during deployment all having same `tag`. I can manually change all the `tag` value and I can run it `kubectl apply -k .` through command prompt.

Question is, I don't want to change this file manually, I want to send `tag` value as a command line argument within `kubectl apply -k .` command. Is there way to do that? Thanks.

```js
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../../base
images:
- name: foo/bar
  newTag: "36"
- name: zoo/too
  newTag: "36"
```

Comment: I don't have time to test it right now, but maybe you can use ENV vars with some tricks. Check https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/2301

Comment: Thanks @whites11 . I didn't get it fully. Whenever you have time, please suggest how to do in my case. Appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It my opinion using *"**file**"* approach is the correct way and the best solution even while working with your test scenario.

By the *"**correct way**"* I mean this is how you should work with kustomize - keeping your environment specific data into separate directory.

> kustomize supports the best practice of storing one’s entire configuration in a version control system.

1. Before `kustomize build .` you can change those values using:

```
kustomize edit set image foo/bar=12.5

apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
...
images:
- name: foo/bar
  newName: "12.5"
```

2. Using `envsubst` approach:

- `deployment.yaml` and `kustomization.yaml` in `base` directory:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- deployment.yaml


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: the-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 1  
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: foo/bar:1.2
```

directory tree with test overlay:

```
├── base
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   └── kustomization.yaml
└── overlays
    └── test
        └── kustomization2.yaml
```

- Create new `kustomization2.yaml` with variables in `overlay/test` directory:

```
cd overlays/test
cat kustomization2.yaml

apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../../base
images:
- name: foo/bar
  newTag: "${IMAGE_TAG}"
```

```
export IMAGE_TAG="2.2.11" ; envsubst < kustomization2.yaml > kustomization.yaml ; kustomize build .


output:

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: foo/bar:2.2.11
        name: test
```

Files in directory after `envsubst` :

```
.
├── base
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   └── kustomization.yaml
└── overlays
    └── test
        ├── kustomization2.yaml
        └── kustomization.yaml
```

3. You can always pipe the result from `kustomize build .` into `kubectl` to change the image on the fly :

```
kustomize build . | kubectl set image -f -  test=nginx3:4 --local -o yaml 

Output:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx3:4
        name: test
```

**Note**:

> [build in solution](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/faq/kustomize/eschewedfeatures/#build-time-side-effects-from-cli-args-or-env-variables)
>
> Build-time side effects from CLI args or env variables
>
> Changing kustomize build configuration output as a result of additional >arguments or flags to build, or by consulting shell environment variable >values in build code, would frustrate that goal.
>
> kustomize insteads offers kustomization file edit commands. Like any shell >command, they can accept environment variable arguments.
>
> For example, to set the tag used on an image to match an environment >variable, run
> `kustomize edit set image nginx:$MY_NGINX_VERSION`
> as part of some encapsulating work flow executed before kustomize build